# Django aggregate query

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a model `Page`, which can have `Post`s on it.  What I want to do is get every `Page`, plus the most recent `Post` on that page.  If the `Page` has no `Post`s, I still want the page. (Sound familiar?  This is a `LEFT JOIN` in SQL).

Here is what I currently have:

`Page.objects.annotate(most_recent_post=Max('post__post_time'))`

This only gets `Page`s, but it doesn't get `Post`s.  How can I get the `Post`s as well?

**Models:**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default = True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: what is `Post` relationship to `Page`?

Comment: models added for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the relationship between the two, you should be able to [follow the relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) quite easily, and increase performance by using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Taking this:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    page = ForeignKey(Page, ...)
```

You can follow the **forward** relationship (i.e. get all the `posts` and their associated pages) efficiently using `select_related`:

```
Post.objects.select_related('page').all()
```

This will result in only one (larger) query where all the page objects are prefetched.

In the **reverse** situation (like you have) where you want to get all `pages` and their associated `posts`, `select_related` won't work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887171/how-to-select-related-on-reverse-foreign-key),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975558/a-left-outer-reverse-select-related-in-django) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096870/django-reverse-relation-with-select-related) question for more information about what you can do.

Comment: I'm trying to get only the most recent post.  `page.post_set.all` seems to have all of them rather than just that one.  how do i get the desired one?

Comment: `page.post_set.all().latest()` in the view or `page.post_set.all.latest` in the template. You need to specify a `get_latest_by` field in the `Meta` class of your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Comment: if you're using that method, what's the point of even getting the `most_recent_post=Max('post__post_time')`?  You could get it from `post_set.all.latest.post_time`, no?

Comment: Okay, so the problem is it queries every time you run `.all()` or `.latest()` http://pastebin.com/5SKGcSPS

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer to clear up a few things that I misunderstood myself

Comment: marking this as correct.  I ended up doing a raw SQL query.  The various solution for django 1.3 and lower aren't very nice.  Can't wait for django 1.4 to introduce `prefetch_related`..

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to use the techniques described in the django docs here: [Following Links Backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

After you do:

```
pages = Page.objects.annotate(most_recent_post=Max('post__post_time'))
posts = [page.post_set.filter(post_time=page.most_recent_post) for page in pages]
```

And then posts[0] should have the most recent post for pages[0] etc. I don't know if this is the most efficient solution, but this was the solution mentioned in another post about the lack of left joins in django.

Comment: This works, but if there were a way to do it with fewer queries that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [database view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29) that will contain all `Page` columns alongside with with necessary latest `Post` columns:

```
CREATE VIEW `testapp_pagewithrecentpost` AS
    SELECT testapp_page.*, testapp_post.*  -- I suggest as few post columns as possible here
    FROM `testapp_page` LEFT JOIN `testapp_page` 
    ON test_page.id = test_post.page_id 
    AND test_post.post_time = 
        ( SELECT MAX(test_post.post_time) 
          FROM test_post WHERE test_page.id = test_post.page_id );
```

Then you need to create a model with flag `managed = False` (so that `manage.py sync` won't break). You can also use [inheritance from abstract Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) to avoid column duplication:

```
class PageWithRecentPost(models.Model):   # Or extend abstract BasePost ?
    # Page columns goes here
    # Post columns goes here
    # We use LEFT JOIN, so all columns from the 
    # 'post' model will need blank=True, null=True 

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Django will not handle creation/reset automatically
```

By doing that you can do what you initially wanted, so fetch from both tables in just one query:

```
pages_with_recent_post = PageWithRecentPost.objects.filter(...)
for page in pages_with_recent_post:
    print page.name        # Page column
    print page.post_time   # Post column
```

However this approach is not drawback free:

- It's very DB engine-specific
- You'll need to add VIEW creation SQL [to your project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data)
- If your models are complex it's very likely that you'll need to resolve table column name clashes.
- Model based on a database view will very likely be read-only (INSERT/UPDATE will fail).
- It adds complexity to your project. Allowing for multiple queries is a definitely simpler solution.
- Changes in `Page/Post` will require re-creating the view.